# Динамическое создание view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

Разработал для заказчика владельца пилорамы приложение, рассчитывающее стоимость сруба по введенным данным. На экране куча editText, пользователь заполняет их данными, данные через DataBinding передаются во ViewModel, юзер нажимает кнопку, во ViewModel все это рассчитывается по формуле и результат выдается на экран. Все это прекрасно работает.

НО есть один нюанс, на данный момент пользователь вводит количество окон, длину и ширину окна, то есть все окна получаются одного размера. Заказчик же говорит есть небольшой процент заказов, в которых окна нужно сделать разного размера и соответственно приложение не может обработать такой вариант и его нужно доработать.

Можно в макете создать ограниченное количество "разных" окон и изначально скрыть их, а на экране сделать CheckBox "Окна одного размера", если он true, то как и раньше выводится длина и ширина окна и их количество, если false то на экране появляются дополнительные поля для длины и ширины каждого окна.

Насколько вообще рационален такой способ? Можно создавать editText динамически, но как тогда это отразить в формуле и передавать из динамических edit'ов данные, плюс неизвестно ведь заранее сколько будет окон "разного размера" и неизвестны id таких окон?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдёт [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView) или [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вынести данные касаемо окна в отдельное view. Вот статья как делать кастомное view из набора стандартных https://dimlix.com/customview-begginer/ там используется ключевое слово merge в верстке, ничего страшного если вы это опустите для начала. Посмотрите сам принцип создания viewGroup и как его использовать.

Далее используйте ListView или RecyclerView в котором по умолчанию лишь одна форма для окна, ниже добавьте кнопку "Добавить окно". Которая добавит еще одну форму для окна. После вы в цикле сможете собрать с них данные.

Comment: благодарю за ответ, попробую реализовать Ваш вариант